# Unable to show Android Heads Up notification with FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, heads-up-notifications

I am working with Firebase to send notifications to a user. I am able to send a basic notification perfectly fine. However, I am having trouble with turning that notification into a heads up notification. I have tried multiple solutions from StackOverflow, but none of them have worked with me.

Below is the respective class I have for receiving push notifications.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel("channel",
                    "Channel description",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "channel")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18)
                        .setContentTitle(message.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this on an Android 8 (Oreo) device? If you had the channel's priority on something different than 'high', this could be the issue. In that case you should uninstall your app and install it again, to wipe the channel from the system. Your code looks okay as far as I can tell,

Answer (score 1):

You should add your listener service, as you would in a standard GCM implementation.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]
```

Run code snippetExpand snippet

Then, register your receiver in AndroidManifest.xml tag to listen on incoming notifications:

```
<!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
<service
    android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
```

This way - you won't have to handle incoming messages separately for cases when app is in foreground vs background.